# Why “records in” is different than “records out” in dd command output

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I'm trying to wipe a USB flash drive of 256 MB using the dd command. I entered this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

and I got this output:

```
499713+0 records in
499712+0 records out
```

Why there is a difference between the number of full blocks read and written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dd` read an (extra) block from `/dev/zero` which it could not write to `/dev/sdb` (since the device was full).  You'd get similar results if you interrupted the program.